# Adding nodes on the fly with Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I'm running a swarm using a static list of IPs and I want to add a node.

The obvious solution would be to quit the swarm created with `swarm manage -H 2375:2375 <node_ip1:2375>` and run `swarm manage -H 2375:2375 <node_ip1:2375>,<node_ip2:2375>`.

Is there another solution to do something like `swarm add <node_ip2:2375>` adding a second node to my running swarm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not you can't add on the fly nodes with list of IPs without restart manually your swarm and adding new hosts. But if you use swarm with service discovery you can do it.

You can found [here](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/) the needed reference to implement docker-swarm with service discovery and how join nodes dynamically. Note that you can use any of these [Discovery backends](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/discovery/).